# Swift: clean up declarations/meta programming

Tags: swift, refactoring, metaprogramming

I have the following declaration:

```
var loginServiceUsed: String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(Constants.loginServiceUsed.rawValue) {
    didSet {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(loginServiceUsed, forKey: Constants.loginServiceUsed.rawValue)
    }
}
var loginServiceToken: String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(Constants.loginServiceToken.rawValue) {
    didSet {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(loginServiceToken, forKey: Constants.loginServiceToken.rawValue)
    }
}
...
```

repeated about half a dozen times.  This much of an identical pattern makes me a little queasy.  If I were writing ruby code, I'd just drop a little meta-programming in there and it would be an array of variable names and the associated 4-5 lines of what they all do - I'd be down to 6ish lines of code.

Is there a good way to clean up these declarations?

I'd be happy to refactor it in such a way to make each of the declarations a one liner - is there some way to do this with a closure?

Comment: Each declaration *IS* a one-liner.   The rest is a `didSet` property observer method.

Comment: Are you dead set on having those as properties? Seems like this should just be a getDefault/setDefault functions using your constants. I would use an enum in this case, but either gets rid of magic strings.

Comment: I do like them as properties.  I'm considering writing a struct with a postfix = operator.  I think that'll be an elegant solution.  loginServiceUsed: NSUserDefaultsBackedVariable(<Type>, key: String).  How would I return the rawValue without calling something like rawValue...

Comment: I don't have any more insight here, making things elegant by adding complexity isn't my thing. But I am curious what you end up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the solution I have isn't nearly as slick as I'd like:

```
struct BackedVariable<type: AnyObject> {

    var key: String

    init(_ key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }

    var value: type? {
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
        get {
            let returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(self.key) as? type
            return returnValue
        }
    }
}

var bv: BackedVariable = BackedVariable<NSString>("backed")
bv.value = "foo"
println("\(bv.value!)") // "foo"
```

So

```
var loginServiceUsed: BackedVariable<String>("loginServiceUsed")
loginServiceUsed.value = "SomeValue"
doSomethingWith(loginServiceUsed.value)
```

It's not horrible, but it's not what I was hoping for.  I can't override the = operator to do a more natural assignment.  I'm considering adding some other operator so I can do

```
loginServiceUser <operator assigns> newValue
```

It encapsulates the repeated complexity, so that's good, anyway.

---

Later...

I can add

```
postfix operator & { }
postfix operator &! { }

func &=<type: AnyObject>(inout oldValue:BackedVariable<type>, newValue: type?) -> BackedVariable<type> {
    oldValue.value = newValue
    return oldValue
}

postfix func &<type>(object: BackedVariable<type>) -> type? {
    return object.value
}

postfix func &!<type>(object: BackedVariable<type>) -> type {
    return (object&)!
}
```

And then do

```
loginServiceUser &= "bar"
println("\(loginServiceUser.value!)") // "bar"
println("\((loginServiceUser&)!)") // "bar"
println("\(loginServiceUser&!)") // "bar"
```

which I'm not convinced is a big win.  But it's probably as good as it's gonna get.